# file-pattern option in int-ftp:outboundgateway not work in recursive mode?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

thanks for attention, i defined `int-ftp:outbound-gateway` adapter with **ls** command in my spring integration project, i want to filter **recursively** `.op` extension files that in my ftp directories and i set `file-pattern` to `*.op` nut not worked, my code is:

```
 <int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
                              session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                              request-channel="inbound"
                              command="ls"
                              filter="ftpFilter"
                              filename-pattern="*.op"
                              remote-directory=""
                              command-options="-R"
                              expression="payload"
                              reply-channel="toSplitter"/>
```

**Update:**
thanks for help @Gary, i used `filename-regex` option Instead of `filename-pattern` to `([foo]|.*\.op)` (for example) and it's work.
For filter multiple subDirectory we can use regular expression `([a-z]*|[a-z]*|.*\.op)` and it's work correctly.

Comment: And why should that be recursive? That will only match files ending in `.op` in the current directory. Something like `**/*.op` might work (although I'm not sure if ant style expressions are fully supported.

Comment: No, we don't currently support any-style patterns in this context; see my answer for the algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that your subdirectories don't pass the filter and hence are not searched. As described in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway), you need to add the subdirectory pattern to your filter...

> ... However, files in the tree can be filtered, by providing a FileListFilter; directories in the tree can also be filtered this way. A FileListFilter can be provided by reference or by filename-pattern or filename-regex attributes. For example, `filename-regex="(subDir|.*1.txt)"` will retrieve all files ending with 1.txt in the remote directory and the subdirectory subDir. If a subdirectory is filtered, no additional traversal of that subdirectory is performed.

So, if you have, say subdirs `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3` etc., you can use

```
filename-regex="(foo[0-9]|.*\.txt)"
```

The first part of the regex passes the subdirs, the second matches files (or directories) ending `.txt`.

It is important to understand how the recursion works. Starting at the top level...

- list files/dirs
- filter files/dirs
- iterate, if a directory, recurse

You can, of course, supply a custom filter to work whatever way you want (e.g. don't filter directories).

Comment: how to set multiple directory in expression @Gary?

Comment: Use a regex; for more complex scenarios, a custom `FileListFilter` might be easiest. If you need help with the regex, describe your directory tree.

Comment: thanks @Gary , in my case ([a-z]*|[a-z]*|.*\.op) , only first level worked?